# A subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$  be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. Show that $A=\{0\}$ or $A\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

My intuition is to do something with the generator(s) of A (maybe it's not the best thought), but I have no idea how to start the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $A \neq \{0\}$ then $A$ must contain a positive number (why? inverses!) so there exists a smallest positive number in $A$, call this $a$.  Define $\mathbb Z \to A$ by $n \mapsto na$ and try to show that this is surjective (use the remainder theorem) and injective (easy).